# jqGrid - groupCollapse on init but after search unCollapse

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, grouping

I have a jqGrid that is using the toolbar search with some text searches for businessName and a dropdown for states. I am using the grouping feature to group by state and this works great. I have also set the option of *groupCollapse* to *true* so basically loads a grid of states with their count of businesses.

```
groupText: ["{0} - {1} businesses"],
groupCollapse:true
```

Then for my toolbar search bar *filterToolbar*

```
$("#businessGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false, 
    afterSearch : function(){
   $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', 
          {'groupCollapse':false}
      ).trigger('reloadGrid');
      var x = $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','groupCollapse');
      console.log(x);
    }
```

});

When I log [ *x* ] it is indeed setting the gridParam to false but when I trigger a reload of the grid it doesn't un-collapse the groups.

Any ideas would be appreciated. If its not possible I'll have to come up with a different solution, but this behavior would be ideal.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think i found the solution removes the grouping which is fine since only one state can be chosen at once any way.

```
///if blank option (all states option) is chosen reapply grouping 
if($("#gs_StateFull").val() == "") {
   $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{'grouping':true}).trigger('reloadGrid');
} else {
   $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{'grouping':false}).trigger('reloadGrid');  

}
```

EDIT: Since groupCollapse inside the groupingView object it needed to be set using the syntax below. THis keeps the grouping intact as well

```
///if blank option (all states option) is chosen reapply grouping 
if($("#gs_StateFull").val() == "") {
   $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{groupingView: { groupCollapse : true} }).trigger('reloadGrid');
} else {
   $("#businessGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{groupingView: { groupCollapse : false} }).trigger('reloadGrid');   

}
```